# Compare two dataframes using Python

Tags: python, list, merge, compare, match

I have two dataframes, each has three columns with same column name. I would like to compare the values of two dataframes by putting them together based on the first column.

I tried using outer join, left join and even inner join. The output are actually the same and also correct. But I only want the values of second and third columns to be listed out (side by side) if there are match on the first column. Using join method would result in duplications. Attached picture is the output I get and also my targeted output.

```
# Merge the two tables on column A
merged_table = pd.merge(dfA, dfB, on='Fruit', how='outer', suffixes=('_from dfA', '_from dfB'))

# Sort the merged table by column B
merged_table = merged_table.sort_values('Date_from dfA')

# Display the output
print(merged_table)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this is to add another column based on the fruit group to data frames and then merge based on both fruit and the new column, the code would look like this:

```py
    dfA=dfA.assign(num=(dfA.groupby(['Fruit']).cumcount()+1))
    dfB=dfB.assign(num=(dfB.groupby(['Fruit']).cumcount()+1))

    merged_table = pd.merge(dfA, dfB, on=['Fruit','num'], how='outer', suffixes=('_from dfA', '_from dfB'))
```